# Mostrar boton al tener "n" checkbox activos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una duda y no se como resolverla, quiero que un botón solo aparezca cuando tenga todos mis checkbox activos por ejemplo 3. Y que este botón desaparezca cuando uno, dos o todos estén desactivados. Tengo lo siguiente pero creo que estoy mal

```
$(function(){
$('.seleccionU, .seleccionD, .seleccionT').change(function(){
if(!$(this).prop('checked')){
    $('#btnOculto').hide();
}else{
    $('#btnOculto').show();
}
```

Siendo .seleccionU, .seleccionD, .seleccionT, las clases de mi checkboxes

```
<input class="seleccionU" type="checkbox"  name="option1" id="option1">
<input class="seleccionD" type="checkbox"  name="option2" id="option2">
<input class="seleccionT" type="checkbox"  name="option3" id="option3">
```

Y este es mi boton

```
<button id="btnOculto" >
<span>Regístrate</span> </button>
```

Quedo atento a sus comentarios, Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como menciona alanfcm puedes emplear una clase general para n numeros de checkboxs, en mi caso haría algo similar a esto:

```
   $(function(){
        $('.opcion').change(function(){
            var showBtn = true;
            $(".opcion").each(function() {
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                    showBtn = false;                
                }      
            });
            if (showBtn) {
                $('#btnOculto').show();
            } else {
                $('#btnOculto').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar una clase general a todos los checkboxes, digamos seleccion, y luego lo harias asi:

```
$(function(){
$('.seleccion').change(function(){
    var cont = 0;
    $(".selection").each(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            cont++;                
        }      
    });
    if (cont == 3) {
        $('#btnOculto').show();
    } else {
        $('#btnOculto').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Corrige el error de tu respuesta.